# Sort Month-Year multidimensional array in PHP using uksort

Tags: php

I want to sort the following array:

```
Array(
    [05/2017] => Array (
        [city] => 'ABC'
        [memebers] => '50'
    )
    [03/2017] => Array (
        [city] => 'ABC'
        [members] => '25'
    )
    [10/2016] => Array (
        [city] => 'ABC'
        [members] => '20'
    )
    [11/2017] => Array (
        [city] => 'ABC'
        [members] => '65'
    )
)
```

The expected result:

```
Array(
    [10/2016] => Array (
        [city] => 'ABC'
        [members] => '20'
    )
    [03/2017] => Array (
        [city] => 'ABC'
        [members] => '25'
    )
    [05/2017] => Array (
        [city] => 'ABC'
        [members] => '50'
    )
    [11/2017] => Array (
        [city] => 'ABC'
        [members] => '65'
    )
)
```

I'm using `uksort` to sort it, but I guess `uksort` does not work with multidimensional array:

```
uksort($data, function($a1, $a2) {
    $time1 = strtotime($a1);
    $time2 = strtotime($a2);

    return $time1 - $time2;
});
```

Please suggest how will it work with `uksort` or any other possibility?

Comment: strtotime() is returning false because it can't parse this format.... consider using DateTime::createFromFormat() instead

Comment: It would be great if you could just create this array with YM instead of MY keys instead. Then you could just use `ksort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works :

```
$data = 
    array(
        '05/2017' => array (
            'city' => 'ABC',
            'memebers' => '50'
        ),
        '03/2017' => array (
            'city' => 'ABC',
            'members' => '25'
        ),
        '10/2016' => array (
            'city' => 'ABC',
            'members' => '20'
        ),
        '11/2017' => array (
            'city' => 'ABC',
            'members' => '65'
        ),
    );

uksort($data, function($a1, $a2) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y|', $a1) <=> DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y|', $a2);
});

var_dump($data);
```

You need to use DateTime since your dates are not well formated, then just compare the timestamps. As pointed by Mark, use "m" for months, and you can use "<=>" operator **(since PHP 7)**

Comment: I suggest  that it should be `m/Y` (for month/year) rather than `d/Y`; and you probably also want to use `m/Y|` to force it to the first of the month and avoid problems like 31st February at the end of the month

Comment: And you can do a simple comparison of DateTime objects, even use the `<=>` operator

Comment: Accept the answer so :)